class extends another class based on instance
I am looking for below solution:
class BasicTable {
  addData() {
    console.log("******** BasicTable");
  }
}

class BasicHtmlTable extends BasicTable {
  override addData() {
    console.log("--------- BasicHtmlTable");
  }
}

class Table<T extends BasicTable | BasicHtmlTable> extends BasicTable {
  printData() {
    console.log("--------- Table");
    super.addData();
  }
}

class A extends Table<BasicTable> {
  test() {
    this.printData();
  }
}

class B extends Table<BasicHtmlTable> {
  test() {
    this.printData();
  }
}

const aInstance = new A();
const bInstance = new B();

aInstance.test(); 
bInstance.test();

For class A, I want to use methods from BasicTable.
For class B, I want to use methods from BasicHtmlTable.
But my implementation always uses methods from  BasicTable instead of BasicHtmlTable.
I need suggestion to implement this in typescript.
mentioned in details

Your class B still inherits from Table which inherits from BasicTable which inherits from Report. Nothing in here inherits from BasicHtmlTable. The generic type parameter is irrelevant.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] this code to be a [mre]. In particular, you'll need to add some members to your classes so they can be distinguished structurally (empty classes make for poor examples) and ideally you'll show code that fails where you expect it to succeed.

What is the point of Table at all? Which of your classes actually have any methods, and which? You don't need to post the entire class, but at least the most important method signatures; an empty class is useless and we cannot judge your code based on it.

@Bergi   I updated code.

What is the point of the <T extends BasicTable | BasicHtmlTable> generic type parameter? You are not using T anywhere!

Ahh, you're looking for Table to be a mixin, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

TypeScript generics are used for type-checking at compile time but don't affect runtime behavior.
Table class is defined to extend BasicTable. The generic type T ensure  that T can only be BasicTable or BasicHtmlTable (and validated during complication), but it does not change the fact that Table extends BasicTable.
If you want B to extend BasicHtmlTable, you can use composition instead of inheritance (see code example below).
class Table<T extends BasicTable> {
    constructor(private table: T) {
        super();
    }

    printData() {
        console.log("--------- Table");
        this.table.addData();
    }
}

class A extends Table<BasicTable> {
    constructor() {
        super(new BasicTable());
    }

    test() {
        this.printData();
    }
}

class B extends Table<BasicHtmlTable> {
    constructor() {
        super(new BasicHtmlTable());
    }

    test() {
        this.printData();
    }
}

(You can probably get similar results using other design as well, but composition is a well known concept)

When using composition, Table shouldn't extend BasicTable any more. Otherwise you'd have both a.addData() and a.table.addData(), and have them doing different things.

At best, use implements BasicTable, with a addData(...args) { return this.table.addData(...args); } method for a proxy pattern

@Bergi I agree, it is just a quick code demo that uses the original code and alter it a bit.
